# Return value from query statement - jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax, jquery form which works fine, but returning a message from `<div></div>`.  I want to return a value from a db query, a single value.

How do I go about doing it.

Thanks
Dave

Comment: can you provide an example? the question is not very clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "returning a message from <div></div>" ? You need to query the database in your server side script and return that value. Showing your code would make it easier to help. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can return your result in any form you want. I used to return my result as formatted html and then used that as the innerHTML for a div. It all depends on how you process your result I guess.

For your situation, just return your result as an ordinary string (e.g. echo $result in your php backend code). Then you could cast/convert the value to whatever form you want in your javascript/jquery frontend.

I hope I understood your question right